# Excel VBA labelling a second data series

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a multiple chart trend template that dynamically updates using the offset function depending on user input.

I have been able to label the first data series using a defined name that uses the offset function, but I have been unable to label the second data series in the same way ...

So INDEX(name,1) works to pull the relevant part of the array within a cell ...

Is there a way to dynamically create a number of textboxes and link to named cells?  Possibly something like this? [Attaching a Textbox to a point or line on a chart in Excel/VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582636/attaching-a-textbox-to-a-point-or-line-on-a-chart-in-excel-vba)

The following code works but only with the set of defined names in one worksheert. Is there a way to modify this for multiple charts, using named cells on different worksheets?

```
Sub Add_Text_to_point()

Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

' loop through sheets in this workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
' loop through Chartobjects in sheet
For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects
    ' no need to select the chart or the series use With statement instead
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(1)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point1]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(2)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point2]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(3)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point3]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(4)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point4]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(5)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point5]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(6)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point6]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(7)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point7]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(8)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point8]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(9)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point9]
    End With
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(10)
            .DataLabel.Text = [Point10]
    End With
    Next objCht
 Next ws
```

Comment: It need information of your sheet's data  and your chart type. There is another method.

Comment: Don't use square brackets as a shortcut to cell references. Try `.DataLabel.Text = Worksheets("Some Sheet").Range("Point1").Text`